# Port ubuntu touch: segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, segmentation-fault

I asked previous question 2 weeks ago and don't got answer on it. This question still actual. I follow [this](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/porting-new-device/) guide to build my own ubuntu touch firmware and stuck on **build your first Ubuntu image for a Nexus 4** and don't know how to fix it.

All previous steps i complied without any errors. To check it I do it for second time.

Firstly I try install phablet-tools typing **sudo apt-get install phablet-tools**:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
phablet-tools is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Looks like all is fine. Ok next i try to install other packages I need for the build typing:

```
sudo apt-get install git gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential \
  zip bzr curl libc6-dev libncurses5-dev:i386 x11proto-core-dev \
  libx11-dev:i386 libreadline6-dev:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 \
  libgl1-mesa-dev g++-multilib mingw32 tofrodos \
  python-markdown libxml2-utils xsltproc zlib1g-dev:i386 schedtool \
  g++-4.8-multilib
```

Result:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
bison is already the newest version.
build-essential is already the newest version.
flex is already the newest version.
g++-multilib is already the newest version.
gperf is already the newest version.
python-markdown is already the newest version.
tofrodos is already the newest version.
xsltproc is already the newest version.
zip is already the newest version.
mingw32 is already the newest version.
schedtool is already the newest version.
libncurses5-dev:i386 is already the newest version.
libreadline6-dev:i386 is already the newest version.
libx11-dev:i386 is already the newest version.
zlib1g-dev:i386 is already the newest version.
bzr is already the newest version.
curl is already the newest version.
g++-4.8-multilib is already the newest version.
git is already the newest version.
gnupg is already the newest version.
libc6-dev is already the newest version.
libgl1-mesa-dev is already the newest version.
libxml2-utils is already the newest version.
x11proto-core-dev is already the newest version.
libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Next step sync repository **phablet-dev-bootstrap phablet**. Result below:

```
INFO:phablet-dev-bootstrap:Changing to workdir /phablet/phablet
INFO:phablet-dev-bootstrap:Initializing repository

... A new repo command ( 1.22) is available.
... You should upgrade soon:

    cp /phablet/.repo/repo/repo /usr/bin/repo


Your identity is: user <mail>
If you want to change this, please re-run 'repo init' with --config-name

repo has been initialized in /phablet
If this is not the directory in which you want to initialize repo, please run:
   rm -r /phablet/.repo
and try again.

... A new repo command ( 1.22) is available.
... You should upgrade soon:

    cp /phablet/.repo/repo/repo /usr/bin/repo

Fetching project aosp/platform/frameworks/av
Fetching projects:   0% (1/136)  Fetching project aosp/device/asus/flo
Fetching projects:   1% (2/136)  Fetching project aosp/platform/frameworks/base
...
Fetching projects:  99% (135/136)  Fetching project aosp/platform/external/libvpx
Fetching projects: 100% (136/136), done.
Syncing work tree: 100% (135/135), done.
```

So, i'm ready to build.
1 (**. build/envsetup.sh**):

```
including device/asus/deb/vendorsetup.sh
including device/asus/flo/vendorsetup.sh
including device/asus/grouper/vendorsetup.sh
including device/asus/tilapia/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/armv7-a-neon/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/x86/vendorsetup.sh
including device/lge/hammerhead/vendorsetup.sh
including device/lge/mako/vendorsetup.sh
including device/samsung/manta/vendorsetup.sh
including sdk/bash_completion/adb.bash
```

2 (**lunch**):

```
You're building on Linux

Lunch menu... pick a combo:
     1. aosp_arm-eng
     2. aosp_x86-eng
     3. aosp_mips-eng
     4. vbox_x86-eng
     5. aosp_deb-userdebug
     6. aosp_flo-userdebug
     7. aosp_grouper-userdebug
     8. aosp_tilapia-userdebug
     9. mini_armv7a_neon-userdebug
     10. mini_x86-userdebug
     11. aosp_hammerhead-userdebug
     12. aosp_mako-userdebug
     13. aosp_manta-userdebug

Which would you like? [aosp_arm-eng] 12
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=4.4.2
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_mako
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=krait
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-3.4.0+-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=KOT49H
OUT_DIR=/phablet/out
============================================
```

3 (**make**). How you remember before this step I complete all steps without any errors or warnings! And finally i got segfault:

```
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=4.4.2
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_mako
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=krait
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-3.4.0+-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=KOT49H
OUT_DIR=/phablet/out
============================================
Checking build tools versions...
including abi/cpp/Android.mk ...
including bionic/Android.mk ...
...
including frameworks/av/media/libnbaio/Android.mk ...
including frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/Android.mk ...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

How to fix it? Nobody can help me?

Comment: I have same problem with AOSP 6.0 but no solution